# Dragging the mouse down to reveal a panel? (using MooTools)

Tags: javascript, css, html, mootools

I have a simple DIV panel that I want to slide in when the user clicks and drags a smaller tab. There are plenty of tutorials for showing on click and sliding elements etc, but this requires the user to click once on a button to reveal the panel.

Comment: But if it requires the user to click and drag, isn't that what you want?

Comment: You need element continue moving after releasing mouse button, or in other words: inertia effect, don't you?

Comment: The panel would reveal itself when the user clicks and drags on a button. It would reveal x pixels depending on the y position of the cursor. Inertia? I assume yes. Edit, I see what you mean sdleihssirhc. I meant they require the user to simply click the element once to reveal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I understand, you'd need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/pvdXa/

I made this mock-up in a min..

markup:

```
<div id="handler"></div> <!-- your 'tab' to drag -->
<div id="toSlide">content to be revealed</div> <!-- content to slide in/out -->
```

js :

```
var toSlide = document.id('toSlide'); //get the content div
document.id('handler').makeDraggable({
    limit:{x:[10,10],y:[10]}, //setting limits
    onDrag:function(elem){ //while user drags, set the content height
        toSlide.setStyle('height',elem.offsetTop-10); 
    }
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is looking very promising. I'll have to give it a go.

Comment: After spending a lot of time tweaking it to make it work, I found that I needed the drag module for MooTools. I just started MooTools a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

I would add, for the sake of usability, clicking and dragging. I'll not provide the code, it's complex plugin if you want to do it "right" ;)

`Drag` has the `onCancel` event, where you can check if the user actually started dragging or just clicked or long-clicked the draggable element.

For the dragging you can a) set a limit, so the user doesn't open the element all the way or b) stop dragging after opening the slider for `x` pixels and sliding the rest of the way with an animation. This way it acts like the touch slider you know from mobile phones, where an initial short touch slide initiates opening a dropdown/menu/navigation.

Comment: hi @digitarald ..so, my example is not so correct to achieve what the questioneer wants to obtain.. if I'm not wrong, the intent is to drag from x to x+x1 (or from y to y+y1), and when a bound (x1 or y1) is reached then the content is revealed.. no?
p.s. fancyUpload FTW :)